# How do I randomly match two records from a table in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn rails by running through some basics and also trying to solve a problem that would help me save time if I got it working. I need to match each volunteer from my volunteer table to another volunteer at random. I want the matched assignments displayed on a new page. How would I do this? My volunteers page look like this:[image]

Here's what I am trying currently:

```
def index
  @volunteers = Volunteer.all
  @volunteers.each do |element|
    item = @volunteers[rand(@volunteers.length)]
    if (element == item)
      puts 'failed to find you a match. try again.'
    else
      puts element
      puts item
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot simple lime! I was having frustrations with the formatting as you can tell

Comment: You are not displaying html code on the page but using puts. Is this the problem you want to solve or is there any other problem with the code?

Comment: Maybe its only me, but i didn't get whats the result should be? the image you included shows how your page looks now, but do you want to include the data of the `puts` as well in the page? Or maybe only the volunteers that have match? or maybe those who doesnt have a match? can you please edit your question and add some more info?

Answer (score 0):

you should move the logic for creating a random connection out of your index and make a separate function in your model for that, then call it in your index action.

in your controller do something like

```
def index
  @volunteers = Volunteer.connections
end
```

in your Volunteer model make a function to handle the connections between volunteers

```
def connections
  make some call using the Random function rand()
end
```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. Additionally it would be `def self.connections`